# Haskell IDE for Windows?

Tags: windows, haskell, ide

I really searched on this one.
(E/TextMate is the closest I found in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68504/what-are-my-ide-editor-choices-for-haskell), but it doesn't seem to be that big of deal)

I tried emacs, but I don't seem to find a Haskell Mode for Windows..
VisualHaskell doesn't seem to follow the new VisualStudio updates...

I could try VIM, but does the Haskell Mode works for Windows there?

Sigh... All the time the 'close but no cigare' feeling.

Is there actually so out there programming Haskell under Windows?

Comment: Haskell-Mode works fine on Windows.

Comment: Haskell.org provides [a list of Haskell IDEs][1]


  [1]: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/IDEs

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I think the main IDE-ish options for Windows are, in order:

1. [Using Eclipse as your Haskell IDE](http://sdasrath.blogspot.com/search/label/Haskell)
2. [Leksah](http://www.leksah.org/index.html), an integrated IDE for Haskell written in Haskell.
3. [Visual Haskell](http://haskell.org/visualhaskell/screenshots.html)  (unknown recent status)
4. [Vim + Haskell](http://projects.haskell.org/haskellmode-vim/screencasts.html)
5. [Emacs + Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Emacs)

I use option 4.

Comment: My question was not what the IDE-options were, but what are IDEs for windows.. Do you use option 4 undre windows?

Comment: Oh, these are all windows-specific.

Yes, I use vim on windows when I program on windows.

Comment: I will go for option 5, if you are sure that it can?  I'll try it out and accept your answer later if i can make it work. Concerning Leksah : not simple to make it work in windows and only a beta?

Comment: Emacs+Haskell mode definitely works under Windows.  If you feel brave you may additionally install [Scion](http://github.com/nominolo/scion/) which adds a (currently) very small number of extra features, but it probably doesn't work smoothly enough, yet, if you are a Haskell newbie.

Comment: @OJ Except for finding out where a particular data type is imported from or refactoring.

Comment: As of October 2015, EclipseFP is no longer maintained, and, at least for me, does not work properly
http://jpmoresmau.blogspot.fr/2015/05/eclipsefp-end-of-life-from-me-at-least.html

Comment: The "Visual Haskell" link is broken

Answer (score 11):

**Tip for Emacs on Windows:**

- Download [ntemacs](http://ntemacs.sourceforge.net/) and extract ntemacs24-bin-xxxxxxxx.7z in your favourite location e.g. `D:\`
- Create desktop shortcut for `D:\ntemacs24\bin\runemacs.exe` and run Emacs
- Go to `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\.emacs.d\`
- Create a directory `haskell-mode` and put in it files: `haskell-mode.el`, `haskell-font-lock.el`, `haskell-doc.el` from [Haskell mode for Emacs](http://code.haskell.org/haskellmode-emacs/)
- In `..\emacs.d\` create a file `init.el`

First 8 lines are optional and depend on the preferences.

```
(tool-bar-mode -1)
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
(setq-default truncate-lines t)

(setq line-number-mode t)
(setq column-number-mode t)

(set-keyboard-coding-system 'cp1250)
(prefer-coding-system 'windows-1250)

(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Consolas-11")

(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq default-tab-width 4)

(load "~/.emacs.d/haskell-mode/haskell-mode")

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.hs\\'" . haskell-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.lhs\\'" . literate-haskell-mode))
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook 'turn-on-haskell-doc-mode)
```

That's it!

Ps [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) has syntax support for Haskell.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), which is easily the best general-purpose code editor I've encountered. It generally fills the same niche as Vi/Vim or EMACS, but generally follows modern interface standards, and has some really useful features that I haven't seen in any other editors, such as the minimap and multi-selection (hit ctrl-d with some text selected, and it will select the next instance of the same text, while still keeping the old selection intact, essentially putting your input cursor in two places, so you can edit them both in tandem).

The standard download comes with basic Haskell syntax highlighting. If you want more functionality, there is a plug-in called SublimeHaskell that adds Cabal support for much smarter auto-completion and limited linting. To install that, you first want to install [Sublime Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) (very easy to do, just copy a string from their Installation section into Sublime's internal command-line), restart Sublime, and use the package control to install SublimeHaskell (hit ctrl-shift-p, type "package", select "Package Control: Install Package", then type "haskell" and select "SublimeHaskell", then restart Sublime).

It even has the ability to build from within the editor (Tools -> Build, or ctrl-b). This feature only supports a limited set of languages, but fortunately Haskell is one of them.

Answer (score 4):

## SublimeText

[**Sublime Text**](http://sublimetext.com) is a very stylish and comforting editor. It's not an IDE but it can build your project, work with it as a project and is highly customizable. In difference to IDEs it's very lightweight and the "Distraction free" feature is just mindblowing. It is also cross-platform, seamlessly supporting all three major OSs.

After installation of [**Soda Theme**](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme) it becomes even more pleasant for the eye.

### SublimeHaskell plugin

There is also a third party plugin [**SublimeHaskell**](https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell), which enables the editor with in depth support for cabal, linting, autocompletion and stuff like that.

The only thing the SublimeText solution cannot do yet is refactoring, but then again none of the competing solutions can.

Comment: Agreed, I use Sublime Text 2 almost exclusively for Haskell on Windows.  Soda theme dark is definitely recommended.  That said, on Linux it is emacs.

Comment: @nightski , how do you handle indentation in Sublime Text 2? Would you share your settings?

Answer (score 3):

Emacs works fine on Windows. I used it when I worked with Haskell on Windows. So, that's my recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Haskell works fine for me.

Comment: I don't see a VS2008 version of it on the site?

Comment: Or do you use it under VS2005?

Comment: I think there is no VS2008 support. I use it under vs2005, only to edit code and build my project. And my project wasn't so very big)

Answer (score 2):

Leksah is not bad, install haskell platform, then download the latest Leksah, you're all set. it's not as robust as VS, but it has other qualities which make me enjoy using it, including ease of creating cabal packages, syntax highlighting, auto-completion of function names (they should extend this to syntax as well), function search, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Leksah looks very much like a Linux application, you will see it more when you try to open a file. It does not look like a windows native app. Otherwise, its OK. Eclipse is always good but they say on their website that they have Haskell as their foremost thing right now (2/26/2011). I should look at other options too, so far I have also used Notepad++.

Comment: As I know, Gtk applications do not look native on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I did some Haskell back at varsity and I must admit that I used notepad. There wasn't an IDE back then.

Answer (score 0):

haskellmode-vim works just fine on Windows -- I use it there. It's my preferred Haskell IDE.

See http://projects.haskell.org/haskellmode-vim/

Answer (score 0):

I use [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) .
It has haskell syntax highlighting, it only needs to switch on haskell tabulation mode (4 spaces instead of tab) in preferences, but it is not a big deal.