# editor for haskell under windows 7 with autocomplete?

Tags: haskell

do somebody know one?
need haskell autocomplete under windows 7

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell IDE for windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734309/haskell-ide-for-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Leksah](http://leksah.org/) is an IDE written in haskell, and it has autocompletion. I think it works under windows 7; here's the link http://leksah.org/packages/leksah-0.8.0.6.exe but I think a new version compatible with GHC 7 is about to be released.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like EclipseFP version 2.0.3 (just release) lets you create "code completion templates". Perhaps this would help?
http://jpmoresmau.blogspot.com/2011/03/eclipse-203-released.html