# "-- file:" in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I've been reading my textbook and here's something bothering me:
One of the page shows some code like this:

```
-- file: ch02/add.hs
add a b = a + b
```

Then load it in ghci. However, when I type the first line it ghci, it does nothing, then the second line triggered an error.

I guess these two lines mean that I should create a file and put them in, then load it. But the ghci told me it couldn't recognize "--", though the second line performed well as a function. So I'm confused: shouldn't "--" mean something like "//"? Did I misunderstand the textbook?

Thank you.

Comment: First you say that the first line did nothing and the second gave an error. Then you say that the first line gave an error ("ghci told me it couldn't recognize "--") while the second performed well. Which is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, loading a file is *not* the same as typing lines in ghci. ghci works like in a `do` block of some `IO` action (hence you'd need to write `let add a b = a + b`), whereas a Haskell file simply contains top-level declarations.

FWIW, you can simply leave out the first line. As you've noticed, that's just a comment. The problem in your file is that you have **not** written

```
-- file: ch02/add.hs
```

but

```
— file: ch02/add.hs
```

(you're probably using a text editor which merges two hyphens to an em-dash). And the em-dash isn't recognised as a special symbol in Haskell. Actually, it can be used like any other infix:

```
(—) :: Int -> Int -> Int
a — b = a - b
```

Use a proper plaintext editor or IDE and you shouldn't have such problems, for advice [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734309/haskell-ide-for-windows).